# Как нарисовать кольцо с помощью стилей?

Tags: html, css, css3

Приветствую! Подскажите, как нарисовать такую 
[image: фигуру кольцо] с помощью стилей (т.е. основной упор на прозрачную окантовку, а после нее на границу того же фона)?

```css
.product-category {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
  display:block;
  line-height:60px;
}
```

```html
<a class="product-category" href="#">Иконка</a>
```

Если делать с помощью тени, то получаем вот такой неприятный эффект:
[image: неприятный эффект]

Comment: сделайте просто элемент в элементе с паддингом

Comment: @Etki с прозрачным паддингом? не понимаю вас
промежутки должны быть прозрачными, если что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вложите его в круг:

```css
.blue {
    background-color: #00f;
}

.border {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}

.border {
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    background-color: #0f0; /* или закоментить */
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    width: 80px; height: 80px;
}

.border:hover {
    border: 4px solid orange;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.border .product-category {
    background-color: #0f0;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display:block;
    line-height:60px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 70px; height: 70px;
}

.border:hover .product-category {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue">
    <span class="border">
        <a class="product-category" href="#">Иконка</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: отличный. Но, если вы не против - еще 1 нюанс. А если такой эффект появляется по ховеру, т.е. изначально кружок зеленый, а трансформируется в оранжевый с кольцом - как тогда быть?

Comment: Добавить анимацию на ховер, которая меняет цвет и увеличивает паддинг

Comment: @Вася Добавил в код ответа :hover.

Comment: @Дмитрий спасибо, но оказывается у меня еще 1 фигня есть: `.product-category {}` - это элемент таблицы - прилипает к верхнему левому углу блока и на него марджины не действуют, и так тоже не.. ` display: table-cell; border-spacing: 5px;`

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, добавить:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px 100px orange, 0 0 0px 5px orange;
border: 5px solid transparent;
```

При этом убрать `background-color`. Прозрачный `border` разделит тень и внутреннюю тень, которая со своими значениями выступает в качестве фона элемента.

Comment: задумка красивая! но, этот эффект мне нужен для ховер эффекта. а йвет круга уже изначально с `background-color`

Comment: А  задать элементу изначально вместо цвета фона внутреннюю тень нет возможности? Смотрится неплохо: http://jsfiddle.net/hu4vzzw6/

Comment: возможность есть, но появляется принеприятнейшая тонкая обводочка вокруг элемента..

Comment: Так эта окантовка - граница между двумя тенями. Там же должен быть прозрачный `border`

Comment: проблема в том, что изначально цвет болотный и круг не должен увеличиваться в размерах, из-за чего возникает лаг, который я вверху показал на картинке

Comment: ни прозрачный `border` ни его обнуление окантовку не убирают..

Comment: Чтобы в размерах не увеличивался, добавьте box-sizing: border-box. А вообще вариант с тенями очень интересный

Comment: Последняя попытка) http://jsfiddle.net/hu4vzzw6/1/